# How to override antd style variables when using scss?

Tags: sass, overriding, antd

I am using antd components in my react project. I want to override the specific component's styling in `scss`. I found answers for css but the same thing doesn't work with scss.

I want to override `antd-tooltip-arrow` component's background color.

Comment: Hi @vampireAb everything that works on css will also work on scss can you show us what are you trying to do?

Comment: It didn't. I don't know why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the background color of the antd-tooltip-arrow component using SCSS, you can utilize the `--antd-arrow-background-color` CSS variable. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
// Your SCSS file

.ant-tooltip-arrow-content[style*='--antd-arrow-background-color'] {
 --antd-arrow-background-color: #ffffff !important; 

 // Set your desired background color here and use important if necessary
}
```

- The .ant-tooltip-arrow-content class targets the content of the antd
  tooltip arrow.
- The `[style*='--antd-arrow-background-color']` selector    is used to
  select elements that have inline styles containing the `--antd-arrow-background-color` CSS variable.
- By setting the `--antd-arrow-background-color` variable to your desired
  color, you override the default background
  color of the    tooltip arrow.

Answer (score 0):

In your scss file, add this class 'ant-tooltip' and then type this variable --antd-arrow-background-color and give the color value whatever you want.

```
.ant-tooltip {
  --antd-arrow-background-color: red;
}
```

[Variable color change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/767Ty.png)

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw3l4.png)